# Can I put a fragment on Backstack which hasn't been initialized yet?

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I want to remove a fragment from backstack and put another fragment in its place which hasn't been created yet. Below is a picture of what I want to achieve.

[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @Elltz, it's not possible. So my question becomes

1. Is it possible to destroy the last fragment from back stack?
2. Can I handle the back button pressed manually to provide a different fragment than what is on the back stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**! **NO**! **NO** !

> want to remove a fragment from backstack and put another fragment

you  can not manually re-arrange the `BackstackEntry`. you can only listen,observe and call it. look into `PopBackstack(String name, int flags)` hence *the first no*

> and put another fragment in its place which hasn't been created yet

you mean a `null` `Fragment` ?.. you can not also assign references to `null` object, *the second no*

> Is there any way to accomplish this?

A confirmation No.

**EDIT**

**YES**! **YES**! **YES**!

> Is it possible to destroy the last fragment from back stack?

you can; using [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) & [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

```
FragmentManager fm = FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().remove(
               fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()-1););
```

the first yes

> Can I handle the back button pressed manually to provide a different fragment than what is on the back stack?

Yes, you can, but you have to do it in your `FragmentActivity` or `Activity` so you will need some `interface` or your own logic around that, or 
with your own logic implementing `BackStackChangedListener`, this is actually the `interface` i was talking about with logic, this listener gets notified anytime a `Fragment` goes or leaves the `Backstack`, hence *the second yes*

Third yes was for pampering.

Hope it helps Sir.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually do this, but what you can do is, make these tansitions but hidden

- go to fragment 3 from fragment 2
- go to fragment 4 from 3.

By hidden I mean, that user does not see this happening (you can set the layout visibility as gone).

But this way, Fragment 2 will be in the stack.

To take out fragment 2 from the stack, do the following hidden operations:

- go back to 1
- go to 3 from 1
- go to 4 from 3.

Hope this helps.