# Navigating between Activities and refreshing Views

Tags: android

I have an activity, `MainActivity`, that swaps between seven fragments. The fragments have no particular order, so when the app is launched and the activity is first created, I set one as the default/start screen:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentDrawerContainer);

if (fragment == null)
{
    fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentDrawerContainer, new DefaultFragment())
            .commit();

    // An int I use to track which Fragment is currently being viewed,
    // for navigation drawer purposes
    mCurrentPosition = DEFAULT_FRAGMENT_POSITION;
}
```

From the navigation drawer, the user can also go to a new activity, `SettingsActivity` which hosts a `PreferenceFragment` to change certain settings, such as measurement units (metric vs. imperial) and color themes.

```
// Standard navigation from one activity to another from inside selectItem() method of nav drawer
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Once the user navigates back to `MainActivity` from `SettingsActivity`, either by back or up button, I need two things to happen:

**1)** The fragment the user was looking at last must still be there. Currently, the activity reloads `DefaultFragment` (because the activity is being recreated, I think).

**2)** Each fragment contains a custom View I've written, and the View must update itself using values from `SharedPreferences` after the user returns from `SettingsActivity`.

To solve #1, I've tried using `android:launchMode="singleTop"`, which works, but I can't get the Views to refresh unless I switch to another fragment and then come back.

I've tried calling `myView.invalidate()` in the `onResume()` method of the fragments, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas? Please let me know if I was unclear. Thank you in advance!

Comment: use backstack to see who is currently being shown few post [0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416815/can-i-put-a-fragment-on-backstack-which-hasnt-been-initialized-yet/30417083#30417083), [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686186/android-show-back-button-depending-on-backstack-count/30686674#30686674),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493716/is-there-a-way-to-listen-to-fragmenttransactions-of-a-fragmentmanager/30493931#30493931).. some are indirect. im guess you are calling it on the wrong fragment

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Use onSaveInstanceState method in MainActivity to save current fragment.
Restore it in onCreate method.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's instance
        mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(
                    savedInstanceState, "mContent");
        ...
    }
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

//Save the fragment's instance
getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);


}
```

In the fragment, save instance state by override onSaveInstanceState and restore on onActivityCreated:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's state here
    }
}
...
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

//Save the fragment's state here


}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack)

**2)** In your fragment's onResume method [get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741270/android-sharedpreferences-in-fragment) your shared preferences and set it to views:

```
SharedPreferences preferences =      this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = preferences .getString("key", "default_value");
```